# How many 0.025°x0.025° (lat/lon) squares are there on the globe?

Tags: cartography, latitude-longitude, grids-graticules

Pretty straightforward maths question that I can't wrap my head around. If you were to fill the globe with 0.025°x0.025° squares, how many would it take?

Poles don't matter too much - I know they'd complicate things. Just an estimate would do.

Comment: Math trivia is not related to GIS

Comment: Well, if there are 360 degrees of longitude and 180 degrees of latitude...

Comment: The true question is how many 0.025°x0.025° cells are over or in close proximity to something significant (eg. Land, places of named significance)... now *that's* a GIS question. This would need the terms 'close proximity' and 'significant' qualified and that depends on what you're trying to achieve with your data. If you could give as an idea of what you're trying to achieve here we could be a bit more helpful.

Answer (score 3):

180 degrees of latitude = 7200 0.025° sections from pole to pole

360 degrees of longitude = 14400 0.025° sections along the equator

7200 * 14400 = 1.0368 * 10^8 0.025°x0.025° squares (not actually squares)